# Rails - Twitter API: how to get from ID link to Twitter profile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter

From the Twitter API I obtain user's ID (of course beside profile link, username etc). How can I display the link to user's profile according his ID?

For example, Facebook API provide user's ID as well, and if I put to the browser `www.facebook.com/users_id`, I'll get his profile...

Is there any way to do with Twitter? `www.twitter.com/users_id` returns empty page...

**EDIT:** obviously I can save user's URL (or his username), but the respective user can whenever change it...

Answer (score 1):

what do you call a twitter "profile" ? I guess you talk about the [user timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

according to the api doc, your url should probably look like this :

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.html?&user_id=(your_id_here)
```

however, i would advise to use one of the [twitter api gems](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#ruby) to ease your pain...